# Какую функцию потерь использовать для многоцелевой регрессии?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, регрессия

есть задача написать модель регрессии с несколькими выходами (4) с помощью фреймворка keras
Пытался скомпилировать модель с функцией потерь mse, но выдает ошибку:

**ValueError: A target array with shape (50, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 4) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.**

Искал в интернете, но не смог найти подходящую информацию
Собственно и вопрос: какую функцию потерь использовать?

Вот модель:

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(4))
    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
```

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/

Comment: Спасибо, но Keras API хотелось бы использовать лишь в крайнем случае

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос моделью, мне всего-то нужна функция потерь, по сути это модель с линейным стеком слоев

Answer (score 0):

А вам поставлена учебная задача использовать именно keras? Потому как в
sklearn есть чудненькая [функция MultiOutputRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor)для построения именно многоцелевой регрессии. С автоматическим определением функции детерминации в качестве метрики.

Comment: Это не учебная задача, спасибо за sklearn, но хотелось бы именно с keras, так как еще нужна сверточная основа

Comment: возможно есть смысл написать свою функцию потерь, сравнивающую 4 значения друг с другом

Comment: Вообще стоит задача сегментации объектов, а 4 значения-это координаты двух угловых точек прямоугольника, ограничивающего объект

Comment: @Andrei Вы меня пугаете. Причем регрессия к сегментации???

Comment: Ну смотрите, на вход подаётся изображение, на нём нужно найти лицо
Соответственно есть свёрточная основа, обрабатывающая изображение и регрессор в конце (ведь стоит задача поиска значения на отрезке-числовом отрезке)

Comment: Сейчас приведу модель

Comment: **

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))

model.add(layers.Dense(4))

**

Comment: Получилось криво, дополнил моделью ответ